# How to make my controller work to insert data in mongoDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm trying to insert some data inside my database but I get an error on my `HttpPost`

here it is :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(UserInformationViewModel info)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
    var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Users");
    collection.InsertOne<UserInformationViewModel>(info);
    return View("_ModalContent");
}
```

So i get this error

> The non-generic method
>   'IMongoCollection.InsertOne(BsonDocument,
>   InsertOneOptions, CancellationToken)' cannot be used with type
>   arguments MVCWithMongo    C:\Quentin\Repos\Test\MVCWithMongo\MVCWithMongo\Controllers\UserController.cs   34  Active

I can't figure out why.

If someone could help, would be nice!

I made a modification, i don't have the error anymore but nothing happens.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(UserInformationViewModel info)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var objDatabase = client.GetDatabase("Test");
    var collection = objDatabase.GetCollection<UserInformationViewModel>("Users");
    collection.InsertOne(info);
    return View("_ModalContent");
}
```